# Entity code first migrations and deleting databases

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

We're using EF Code First and migrations for a project. We're commiting our migrations to source, and everything is great. However, if someone delete's their database, or we get a new person on the project, the database will throw errors because it's trying to run the migrations. Is there a way to make it so that if the database doesn't exist, it ignores migrations? I can't seem to find anything about this.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at how you are using DbMigrationsConfiguration from the Entity framework.  You might need something like this in your global asx file:

```
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, YourConfiguration>());
```

Then in your configuration file for migrations you may need something like this:

```
    internal sealed class YourConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }...
```

Without more info and code examples, I can only point you in the right direction.

Comment: Okay, I have `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true` in my configuration file, and I have the `SetInitilizer` in my `AppBootstrapper.cs` file(this isn't aspx, it's a WPF project). It still fails to create several tables because of an error.

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "dbo.Plan" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.` I'm getting that error because the table doesn't exist yet.